# SQLAlchemy Left Outer Join on Dates and Orders is lost on filtering Orders by store. How can I prevent this?

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy

I have a working left join but as soon as I add a filter to select only Orders from a specific store, the left outer join turns into a normal join and I loose the dates where there are no orders.

```py
db.session.query(
        Dates.day_date,
        Orders.date_created,
        Orders.sales
    ).select_from(
        Dates
    ).outerjoin(
        Orders, Dates.day_date == cast(Orders.date_created, Date)
    ).filter(
        Dates.day_date == Orders.date_created
    ).group_by(
                Orders.date_created,
                Dates.day_date
    ).all()
```

| Dates.day_date | Orders.date_created | Orders.sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-01 19:41:17 | 94.8 |
| 2021-02-02 | None | None |
| 2021-02-03 | None | None |
| 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-04 19:21:13 | 24.8 |
| 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-05 13:44:47 | 44.4 |

as soon as I add the filter below I loose the join and the table empty columns vanish.  How do I keep the Dates.day_date values?

```py
.filter(
        Orders.store_id == store.id
)
```

| Dates.day_date | Orders.date_created | Orders.sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-01 19:41:17 | 94.8 |
| 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-04 19:21:13 | 24.8 |
| 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-05 13:44:47 | 44.4 |

---EDIT---
this has been solved by @van

```py
db.session.query(
        Dates.day_date,
        Orders.date_created,
        Orders.sales
    ).select_from(
        Dates
    ).outerjoin(
        Orders, Dates.day_date == cast(Orders.date_created, Date)
    ).filter(or_(
        Orders.store_id == store.id,
        Orders.store_id == None
    )).group_by(
        Orders.date_created,
        Dates.day_date
    ).all()
```

The only problem I have now is that when I test this with multiple stores data. I filter for a specific store.id, but the missing rows still persist when there are None values in the store's order data I am filtering for but not in another stores. I think the "Orders.store_id == None" is looking for None values in all stores, is it possible to combine an 'or' plus an 'and' filter to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how `SQL` query is supposed to behave: given that there is no row for `Orders` table, the filter (translated to `WHERE` clause) will not match, and hence the row will not be returned.

*In fact, i think that even the `.filter(Dates.day_date == Orders.date_created)` might filter those rows there there are no orders. Also the same condition is already a part of the `.outerjoin` condition.*

**Solution**: You could do is to use the `OR` condition:

```
.filter(
    or_(
        Orders.id == None,
        Orders.store_id == store.id,
    )
)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @van for the clarification, still trying to get my head around how SQL works, appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Hi @van, thanks for the help before, it was working great until I tested with another stores data.  The missing Date rows seems to persist when there is None values in one store but not in another.  Any ideas? thanks for you time

Comment: It seems the "Orders.store_id == None" is looking for None values in all stores, how would I work around this, I can't think of how to work it out?  thanks again